# yEd Size Nodes based on association

Tags: nodes, graphing

I have a yEd node/edge chart that was generated from an Excel spreadsheet import. I would like to be able to automatically resize nodes according to the number of other nodes associated with it.

I have not yet been able to determine a solution for this. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update - **Tools > Centrality Measure** effectively solves my issue.